# Build soap message only, using SUDS

Tags: python, soap, suds

Currently I'm struggling while trying to generate soap message with SUDS. Things I want to achieve is something like

`xml_string = client.service.getPercentBodyFat('jeff', 68, 170)`

instead of calling remote procedure I want to get soap message as xml string or object.

Thank You!

Comment: Are you wanting to send pure XML. Could you elaborate on this question?

Comment: I want to prepare xml, for later usage with http client.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the actual remote call, even if the service is not available, you can then capture the request with

```
xml_string = client.last_sent()
print xml_string
```